# Why are CSS properties not being applied to the browser, but are on the tutorial. I did the exact same thing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a tutorial to make a Gemini AI clone using React. But I am stuck. I have come to the stage where I want to add my CSS so I can style the sidebar of the page. I have referenced the CSS of the sidebar with

```
import './Sidebar.css/'
```

But there seems to be no changes to the webpage when I save and refresh the page. It stays how it was without CSS.

The solution I would dearly love is being able to see the changes in the webpage when I make changes to the CSS.

I will link the tutorial and code below:

P.S. If you see the tutorial, he creates a little grey panel on the side to be the sidebar, I have copied this CSS but nothing appears.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?(v=0yboGn8errU&list=WL&index=1&t=924s)=
15:40

**SIDEBAR.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import './Sidebar.css/'
import {assets} from '../../assets/assets'


const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div classname='sidebar'>
      <div className="top">
        <img clasname='menu' src={assets.menu_icon} alt="" />
        <div className="new-chat">
          <img src={assets.plus_icon} alt="" />
          <p>New Chat</p>
        </div>
        <div className="recent">
          <p className="recent-title">Recent</p>
          <div className="recent-entry">
            <img src={assets.message_icon} alt="" />
            <p>What is react ...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="bottom"></div>
      <div className="bottom-item recent-entry">
        <img src={assets.question_icon} alt="" />
        <p>Help</p>
      </div>
      <div className="bottom-item recent-entry">
        <img src={assets.history_icon} alt="" />
        <p>Activity</p>
      </div>
      <div className="bottom-item recent-entry">
        <img src={assets.setting_icon} alt="" />
        <p>Settings</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

**Sidebar.css**

```
.sidebar{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #f0f4f9;
  padding: 25px 15px;
}

.sidebar img{
  width: 20px;
}

.sidebar .menu{
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This is my first time using stack overflow to ask for help and any advice would be dearly appreciated. Of course, if you need any more information, then please let me know!

Thanks so much

Regards

Comment: Why is there a slash (/) after the .css file extension?

Comment: Remove `/` in path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code and you have to fix two issue.

1. change **classname** to **className**
2. change this import './Sidebar.css/' to import './Sidebar.css'

then your code has to work.
Good Luck!